# Proofing the existence of a non-zero congruence class

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $m\ge2$ be an integer. Show that if there is an integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,m)=d\not=1$, then there exists a non-zero congruence class $[x]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, such that $[a]\cdot[x]=[0]$.

I really don't know how to approach this. Any help to get started would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $m = dk$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, try $[a] \cdot [k]$.

Comment: So then $[a]\cdot[\frac md]$ ? What does this accomplish?

Comment: You also know that $a = dq$ for some $q \in \Bbb{Z}$...

Comment: Okay thanks, I got it :)